# How can I return an error from Serde in a function that returns Result<() , Error>

Tags: rust, serde, rust-result

I am attempting to return an error from Serde with a function that returns `Result<(), Error>`:

```
use std::io::{Error};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Mine {
    ab: u8,
    ac: u8,
}
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

fn main() {
    if do_match().is_ok() {
        println!("Success");
    }
}

fn do_match() -> Result<(), Error> {
    match serde_json::from_str::<Mine>("test") {
        Ok(_e) => println!("Okay"),
        Err(e) => return e,
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e48a72d0d51c8bc01079a9f921394a00)

After various attempts, I have been unable to correct the problem to return an error, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are using the wrong error type. `serde_json::from_str`'s `Err` is of type `serde_json::error::Error` whereas you are using `std::io::Error`. Secondly, by pattern matching on `Err(e)` and then trying to `return e`, you are no longer return a `Result` but instead trying to just return something of type `serde_json::error::Error`. Instead, you should be returning `Result<(), serde_json::error::Error>`. Here is the proper way to accomplish what you are trying to achieve:

```rust
fn do_match() -> Result <(), serde_json::error::Error> {
    serde_json::from_str::<Mine>("test").map(|_| println!("Okay"))
}
```

`map` will only perform the `println!(...)` on the result from `serde_json::from_str` if it is an `Ok` variant, otherwise, it will just pass through the `Err` variant. Then, you can just return the resulting expression.

[**Rust Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c648974181aeccea1c24540e7e7f3fd)

Comment: Is there any reason to not implement `std::error::Error` for `serde_json::error::Error`? As a framework developer it can be challenging to handle disparate Error types from Results